# equation center, quantifier push right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, environments

I am looking for an environment that align equations as the following example (from the book by Dunford & Schwartz)

[image]
I mean main equation content is centered and variable, quantifier push to the right. note that align with a single equation does not give me the desired  result since `$f\in F$` is not completely pushed to the right and the integral is not centered.

Well, any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do it with flalign, you'll need lots of &'s. I would not recommend using this design as it is cumbersome to use and does not blend well with eqn numbers. I tend to just use `\qquad f\in F` (through a special macro)

Comment: In my opinion it's very bad style. Just separate the condition with `\qquad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `flalign`, but I consider it quite bad style. I suggest other two possibilities, the final one is what I'd prefer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent % just for emulating the original
conditions guaranteeing that
\begin{flalign*}
&& \int_{0}^{1} f(s)\phi_{n}(s)\,ds \to 0, &&& f\in F.
\end{flalign*}
Where the functions $f$ and $\phi_{n}$ are taken to be
in certain preassigned blah blah blah blah blah

\bigskip

\noindent % just for emulating the original
conditions guaranteeing that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{1} f(s)\phi_{n}(s)\,ds \to 0,\qquad f\in F,
\end{equation*}
where the functions $f$ and $\phi_{n}$ are taken to be
in certain preassigned blah blah blah blah blah

\bigskip

\noindent % just for emulating the original
conditions guaranteeing that, for $f\in F$,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{1} f(s)\phi_{n}(s)\,ds \to 0,
\end{equation*}
where the functions $f$ and $\phi_{n}$ are taken to be
in certain preassigned blah blah blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]

I fixed the obvious typo (*dx* should clearly be *ds*) and, in the final two examples, removed the grammatically wrong period before “where”.

The main formula can be centered by making the condition to have zero width (but this wouldn't work with wider main formulas).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent % just for emulating the original
conditions guaranteeing that
\begin{flalign*}
&& \int_{0}^{1} f(s)\phi_{n}(s)\,ds \to 0{,} &&& \mathllap{f\in F}.
\end{flalign*}
Where the functions $f$ and $\phi_{n}$ are taken to be
in certain preassigned blah blah blah blah blah

\bigskip

\noindent % just for emulating the original
conditions guaranteeing that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{1} f(s)\phi_{n}(s)\,ds \to 0{,}\mathrlap{\qquad f\in F,}
\end{equation*}
where the functions $f$ and $\phi_{n}$ are taken to be
in certain preassigned blah blah blah blah blah

\bigskip

\noindent % just for emulating the original
conditions guaranteeing that, for $f\in F$,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{1} f(s)\phi_{n}(s)\,ds \to 0,
\end{equation*}
where the functions $f$ and $\phi_{n}$ are taken to be
in certain preassigned blah blah blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks egreg! It is a question of style, but I like the condition being at the right, when the context is made clear, it has a kind of "self-containess" when reading.

Comment: @Airlast In my opinion it means nothing, if set down there.

Comment: Yes :) well maybe the example I took was not good but if $F$ is define before, and you forget the "Where the function..." ending equation by a dot.

Comment: @Airlast The period ending the equation is wrong: starting a sentence with “Where the function” doesn't really seem grammatical, but it could be, depending on the following text. In case it is really wanted, I'd use “In cases where…”. About the style: in my opinion it seems to suggest that readers can't read. `;-)`

Comment: I agree that the sentence starting with Where is a bad style. Also I agree that the reader can  read :D You right. 
Just a question (because I am concern in writing stuff well. Do you think I can write:

For all $t\geq 0$,
$$x^1(t) = ... ,$$
and
$$x^i(t) = .... ,$$
for every $i\geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

These variants allow  to have the main equation centred between the margins.

The last solution, in case of consecutive equations with quantifiers towards the right margin,lets all quantifiers begin at the same point on the page, the widest ending exactly at the right margin:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent
conditions guaranteeing that
\begin{align*}
    &   & ∫_0¹f(s)\phi_n(s)\,d\mkern1mu s & \to 0 &   & \mathrlap{f ∈ F. }
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    &   & ∫_0¹f(s)g(s)\phi_n(s)\,d\mkern1mu s & \to 0 &   & \mathrlap{f,  g ∈ F. }
\end{align*}
where the functions  $ f,  g $  and  $ \{\phi_n\} $    are  taken to be in certain preassigned
\vskip 5ex

\noindent
conditions guaranteeing that
\begin{flalign*}
  &     & ∫_0¹f(s)\phi_n(s)\,d\mkern1mu s &\to 0 && \mathllap{f ∈ F. }
\end{flalign*}
\begin{flalign*}
  &     & ∫_0¹f(s)g(s)\phi_n(s)\,d\mkern1mu s &\to 0 & \mathllap{f,  g ∈ F. }&
\end{flalign*}
where the functions  $ f, g $  and  $ \{\phi_n\} $    are  taken to be in certain preassigned
\vskip 5ex

\noindent
conditions guaranteeing that
\begin{flalign*}
  &     & ∫_0¹f(s)\phi_n(s)\,d\mkern1mu s &\to 0 && \llap{\eqparbox{Q}{$ f ∈ F. $} }
\end{flalign*}
\begin{flalign*}
  &     & ∫_0¹f(s)g(s)\phi_n(s)\,d\mkern1mu s &\to 0 & \llap{\eqparbox{Q}{$ f,  g ∈ F. $ }}&
\end{flalign*}
where the functions  $ f, g $  and  $ \{\phi_n\} $    are  taken to be in certain preassigned

\end{document}
```

[image]